# Best mysql indexing practices for queries with sums of fields

Tags: mysql, database

I'm looking to improve the query performance of the following mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM items
     WHERE items.createdAt > ?
       AND items.createdAt + items.duration < ?
```

What are the best indexes to use here? Should I have one for both (createdAt) and (createdAt, duration)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one index on `createdAt`

Then create a generated (aka computed column) column on `createdAt + duration`  and then create an index on the generated column.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily sove the problem.  Indexes are one-dimensional.  You need a 2D index.  `SPATIAL` provides such, but it would be quite contorted to re-frame your data into such.  `PARTITION` sort of gives an extra dimension; but, again, I don't see that as viable.

So, but best you can do is

```
INDEX(createdAt)
```

Or perhaps this is a little better:

```
INDEX(createdAt, duration)
```

I don't see that a "generated" column will solve the problem -- however it *may* lead to *sometimes* running faster for this simple reason:

- If `createdAt > ?` filters out most of the table because `createdAt` is near the end, the `INDEX(createdAt)` appears to be a good index.
- When that `?` is near the *beginning* of time, such an index is essentially useless-- because most of the table needs to be scanned.
- A generated index on `createdAt + duration` has the same problem, just in the other direction.

If the *real* query has an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, there *may* be other tricks to play.  I discuss that when trying to map IP-addresses to countries or businesses:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges